# can not setup main.js file on google cloud parse

Tags: parsing, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to setup a parse on google cloud but can't setup the `cloud/main.js` file
add cloud link on server.js

```
 cloud: "/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/cloud/main.js",
```

I got the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
>       at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at new ParseServer (/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:159:9)
>       error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1

Answer (score 0):

When editing the ‘server.js’ file in ‘/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/’ folder, make sure the ‘cloud’ folder exists and try setting the ‘cloud’ field string to “./cloud/main.js” to point to main.js file in cloud folder, the error could be related to incorrect path. If you are looking to add custom code to the Parse server, please follow the steps provided here [1].

[1] https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/parse/#how-to-add-your-custom-cloud-code-to-your-parse-server-stack